# How do you perforate a teflon sheet?

Tags: materials, experimental-chemistry

I have a sheet of thin unperforated teflon that I need to perforate by tomorrow for a lab I work in. None of my coworkers know how to perforate the sheet. Does anyone know how I can do this using basic tools from my house?

Comment: Can you provide some further infos about the number of holes and the diameter and the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should contact a specialized company, however you should also provide more infos about the diameter and the number of the holes you want. This is an excerpt from [FedTech](http://www.fedtech.com/perforated-sheets.html):

> laser cutting is the method of choice for small perforation, as laser
>   cutting has a smaller, tighter cutting tolerance and thus has the
>   capability to create tiny, intricate perforations. However, if you
>   prefer, abrasive waterjet cutting can be used as well but for larger
>   perforation (.030" and up, respectively). If you prefer to use
>   non-abrasive waterjet cutting, you can create perforations up to .004"
>   in diameter, however this form of waterjet cutting is restricted in
>   cutting certain types of material. With non-abrasive waterjet cutting,
>   you can cut up to about 12" thick from the following: plastic, rubber,
>   foam, composites, silicone, foam, felt, cork, Teflon (PTFE), neoprene,
>   and other soft materials